# upload image to another server codeigniter

Tags: php, upload

I am doing a codeigniter site. My client have two web sites. But he need to handle both sites by a single admin. I have uploaded data to both databses by using multiple database connection. But my problem is how to upload image to another server. is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CURL for this. Something like this should do it.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => '@/path/to/file.txt'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://server2/upload.php');
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

You can then handle the the server2 part as a regular file upload. See [curl_setopt()](https://www.php.net/curl_setopt) for more information on those options.

Comment: Go to your `php.ini` file and remove the `;` mark from the beginning of the following line:

`;extension=php_curl.dll`

Comment: @Ammu Aishrya Rai Ko Kangana Ranaut ne answer diya :)

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. Store images in database
2. Mount remote file system and save as normal file
3. Connect via SSH/FTP and send file

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter provides FTP class to transfer file to the remote server. Using CodeIgniter’s upload and FTP library you can upload images or files to another server easily.

Here is the code for uploading image from local server to remote server.

```
$fileName = 'image.jpg';

//File path at local server
$source = 'uploads/'.$fileName;

//Load codeigniter FTP class
$this->load->library('ftp');

//FTP configuration
$ftp_config['hostname'] = 'ftp.example.com'; 
$ftp_config['username'] = 'ftp_username';
$ftp_config['password'] = 'ftp_password';
$ftp_config['debug']    = TRUE;

//Connect to the remote server
$this->ftp->connect($ftp_config);

//File upload path of remote server
$destination = '/assets/'.$fileName;

//Upload file to the remote server
$this->ftp->upload($source, ".".$destination);

//Close FTP connection
$this->ftp->close();
```

Full source code and tutorial I have found from here - [CodeIgniter : Upload file to remote server](http://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-upload-file-to-remote-server/)